# JSF - session scoped bean shared by browsers on different machines

Tags: java, session, jsf

We have a search form where the filter is bound to a property on a managed bean (session scope). It's not component binding, its property binding like `<h:inputText value="#{searchBean.filter}"/>`.

Submitted data from different machines (different sessions, then) is getting mixed. You search "john", and get "mary" just because the guy beside you have just searched "mary". The value of your `searchBean.filter` is getting **his** submitted data instead of yours.

I've already googled around a lot and found no solution, just an ocurrence of the [same problem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/211420/JSF/java/Session-sharing).

Have anybody faced this issue already? Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Spring (or any other custom EL-resolver) ?

Comment: No. It's plain JSF. I'm using mojarra-1.2_13 with
 `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD = client`. The only different thing we're forced to use is [Infragistics NetAdvantage for JSF](http://www.infragistics.com/java/netadvantage/jsf.aspx).

Comment: Are you copying a URL with a `jsessionid` embedded in it? Are you registering any custom listeners? Have you written any custom renderers?

Comment: No copying with `jsessionid`, no renderers. We use event listeners (methods on the beans like `public void onChange(ValueChangeEvent event)`). Is that the kind of listener you're talking about?

Comment: I was thinking more of state data leaking across threads via global instances (by adding member data to a `PhaseListener`, or servlet `Filter`, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can have two causes:

1. The bean is actually in application scope.
2. The property in question is declared **`static`**.

To fix 1), just ensure that it's in session scope.
To fix 2), just remove the illegal modifier.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Balus! Unfortunately, neither one is happening. I've just ensured that the bean is in session scope and the property is not static.

Comment: Are it actually two physically different machines? How did you actually test it? Firing two instances of the same browser does not use different sessions. Best test would be then to fire one instance of two different browsers each (e.g. one of IE and one of FF). You could debug the Session ID by `${pageContext.session.id}` in page.

Comment: As incredible as it may sound, they're two physically different machines, on different tables, with different people operating them.

Comment: How about session ID? How about other session scoped attributes? How about the listeners/validators/converters? They do not hold some static/instance-specific data do they?

Comment: Using debugging and a tracing `PhaseListener` I could realize that the session scoped bean stops interacting with JSF lifecycle after a new user comes in. Although the right values flow through the lifecycle, it ignores input and don't pass output back to JSF after INVOKE_APPLICATION either. Trouble is I still have no clues about the causes. I've also checked listeners/validators/converters as you advised above, but unfortunatelly that wasn't the case.

Comment: Then I don't see any possible cause unless you didn't elaborate the problem very well. Is it maybe the **result** instead of the **input** which is been shared among sessions? If so, then double check your data layer. The DAO classes, SQL statements and so on. They should also not hold data as static/instance variables.

Comment: I'd be happy if the problem were on DAOs, but I've checked them already. The code isn't mine. I'm about to give up fixing this thing and re-implement it. Well, thanks very much for your effort trying to help. I'll post here the end of this scary story. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Solved!** Finally. Thanks guys, for your attention!

It was something like what Balus guessed at the first time. It was a `static` hidden in a dark corner. I had really double, triple checked everything looking for statics, but -- don't ask me why -- someone created a second bean (`Foo`) which was holding a static reference for `SearchBean`.

In the JSP, there was an `action="#{foo.search}"` instead of `searchBean.search`. Class `Foo` had a method with the same name as in `SearchBean`, that was doing no more than a `searchBean.search();`.

I think pressure for fixing this bug for yesterday didn't allow me to see this trap in the JSP.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Threadsafety issues always boils down to scoping issues (i.e. incorrectly being application or session scoped, or just declared static). Funny that there was a clash with other's code. Maybe been uncareful with some CVS? Anyway if the question is answered please don't forget to set the accepted answer.