# Conflict between type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED and javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException in JSF/Spring/JPA/Hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jpa, transactions

I am trying to port a pure JSF/Hibernate web application to JSF/Spring 3.0/Hibernate/JPA app.
I use dependence injection to inject an instance of EntityManager into my DAO class.
If I  use type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED attribute on the @PersistenceContext annotation, 
    the state is shared across browsers, and the login page does not appear. I tried different browsers, not just different windows
    just like [JSF - session scoped bean shared by browsers on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770610/jsf-session-scoped-bean-shared-by-browsers-on-different-machines)
If I dont specify EXTENDED, I am unable to update my records after the first update and get a javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException

I recently found out about something called View scope, but am not sure whether that is the solution . Please suggest a way to achieve both objectives
a. Avoid OptimisticLockException on subsequent updates
b. Avoid sharing state across browsers

Thanks 
Sagar R. Kapadia

My Configuration and Source Files are as follows

DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

 <bean 
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
     <value>WEB-INF/classes/config/database/db.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

HibernateSessionFactory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

            <prop key="transaction.factory_class">
                net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
            <!-- 
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
                net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
             -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" >2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size"> 5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" >300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>  
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Period.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/ApplicationUser.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Device.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Deal.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/ComboDealItem.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/City.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/DiscountDeal.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/State.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/FreeDeal.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/OrderDetail.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Product.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Country.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Category.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Administrator.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Company.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/ComboDeal.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/compucloud/galleryadmin/entity/Order.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
     </property>    

</bean>
</beans>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
         <variable-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
        </variable-resolver>

    </application>
<!--Navigation rules omitted-->
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>HelloJSF</display-name>

  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



 <filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.compucloud.galleryadmin" />

 <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"></property>
        <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"></property>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"></property>

    </bean>
    <!-- 
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">

    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="demoTxManager"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.compucloud.galleryadmin" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>


    <bean id="demoTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="jpaDaoMethods" 
            expression="execution(* com.compucloud.galleryadmin.databaseutil.Database.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="demoTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="jpaDaoMethods" />
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="demoTxAdvice" transaction-manager="demoTxManager" >
    <!-- 
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="persist*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="reset*" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
            <tx:method name="load*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" />


        </tx:attributes>
         -->
    </tx:advice>

        <!-- 
            <tx:method name="retrieve*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="query*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="false" />
             -->


    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>



    <bean id="database" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.databaseutil.Database" scope="session" ></bean>

    <bean id="country" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Country" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="state" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.State" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="city" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.City" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="administrator" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Administrator" scope="request" ></bean>
    <bean id="companyAdministrator" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Administrator" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="currentAdministrator" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Administrator" scope="session"></bean>
    <bean id="currentCompany" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Company" scope="session"></bean>
    <bean id="company" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Company" scope="request" ></bean>
    <bean id="category" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Category" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="product" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Product" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="deal" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.Deal" scope="request" ></bean>
    <bean id="discountDeal" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.DiscountDeal" scope="request" ></bean>
    <bean id="freeDeal" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.FreeDeal" scope="request"></bean>
    <bean id="comboDeal" class="com.compucloud.galleryadmin.entity.ComboDeal" scope="request"></bean>

</beans>
```

Database.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional

public class Database  implements Serializable{

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager em;


    private Exception lastException;
    private Category category;
    private Country country;  
    private State state;
    private City city;
    private Administrator administrator;
    private Administrator companyAdministrator;
    private Administrator currentAdministrator;
    private Company company;
    private Company currentCompany;
    private Deal deal;
    private DiscountDeal discountDeal;
    private FreeDeal freeDeal;
    private ComboDeal comboDeal;

    //private Deal currentDeal;
    private List<Company>listOfCompanies;
    private List<Country>listOfCountries;
    private List<State>listOfStates;
    private List<City>listOfCities;
    private List<Administrator>listOfAdministrators;
    private List<Administrator>listOfCompanyAdministrators;
    private List<Category> listOfCategories;
    private List<Category> listOfChildCategories;
    private Category currentCategory;
    private Product product;
    private Product productForComboDeal;

    private List<Product>listOfProducts;


    private List<Deal> listOfDeals;
    private List<DiscountDeal> listOfDiscountDeals;
    private List<FreeDeal> listOfFreeDeals;
    private List<ComboDeal> listOfComboDeals;
    /*
    private Session m_Session;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    */
    /*
    private UploadedFile uploadedFileCategory;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFileProduct;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFileProductLarge;*/

    public Database(){

    }
    public void persistWithUpdatedFlag(Object obj){
        obj=em.merge(obj);
        em.flush();
        refreshBeans(obj);
        }

//Other Methods omitted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EXTENDED means that the persistence context will not be closed until you explicitly close it. Since your `Database` is a singleton bean, the EntityManager will live as long as your bean does (which is, forever). That is why you see the same transaction manager across all threads, since there's really only one created in your EXTENDED scenario.

What you want is the "open entity manager in view" pattern, so your entity manager (persistence context) is kept open for the duration of a request, rather than just the transaction. Take a look at the [`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html), for instance.

Comment: I have a spring job, and data seems to populate. I am not flushing myself, so who is?