# Broken HttpSession integrity in distributed WAS7 environment

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

The project is running on WAS7 with load balancing environment, using JSF2.1 and primefaces4. After authentication filter the userinfo is to put it into session. when viewing the page backend bean is getting the user info from session using facescontext like below, bean scope is viewscoped

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        UserInfo userInfo= null;

        if(session != null) {
            userInfo= (UserProfile) session
                    .getAttribute("UserInfo");

           // do some logic
        }
```

Its working fine as expected. when more number user (concurrently) accessing the page or doing same operation in the page at the same time, some times session gives wrong object i.e. other users info object not mine. Based on the user info the all business logic is getting executed, so the page shows wrong info.

Any idea why is this happening, and a solution to prevent this if any ?

Comment: Are you sure WAS 7 is compatible with JSF 2.1? Anyway, maybe you can find this link helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770610/jsf-session-scoped-bean-shared-by-browsers-on-different-machines